# connect OpenVPN client at Ubuntu startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I would like to connect OpenVPN on Startup.

I've added `sudo openvpn /file.ovpn` to the `crontab`, and it doesn't connect at startup.

What is the proper procedure?

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using openvpn as a service? This is the usual way to run something on startup. What version of Ubuntu are you using? I am asking to be able to tell you how to run the service properly as it depends on whether your Ubuntu uses System V init, systemd or something else.

Answer (score 2):

> I've added `sudo openvpn /file.ovpn` to the crontab, and it doesn't connect at startup.

As an admin you typically use cron to schedule recurring jobs, not to run daemons and services that need to start boot.

Additionally, when you have admin rights, you don't use `sudo` in cron jobs, you set the correct user in the `<user>` field of the `/etc/crontab` or the `/etc/cron.d/job.spec` configuration file.

> What is the proper procedure?

Read the manual: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#startup

> **Linux**
>   If you install OpenVPN via an RPM or DEB package on Linux, the installer will set up an initscript. When executed, the initscript will scan for `.conf` configuration files in `/etc/openvpn`, and if found, will start up a separate OpenVPN daemon for each file.

So it may already be sufficient to simply copy your config  file to `/etc/openvpn/connection-name.conf`

---

I recently had to set up OpenVPN on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server and the process was slightly more complicated, since with systemd the init script isn't used any more but instead a *templated* systemd unit file is used.

1. Still copy your config  file to `/etc/openvpn/connection-name.conf`
2. Test if the "connection-name" OpenVPN connection will start with
   `systemctl start openvpn@connection-name`
3. Confirm if the link gets established with:
   `ip addr list` and `ip route list`
   `systemctl status openvpn@connection-name` and/or
   `journalctl --identifier ovpn-connection-name`  and/or
4. Ensure that the service will persist across reboots:
   `systemctl enable openvpn@connection-name`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a .sh under `/etc/init.d` as described [on this Unix & Linux stackexchange page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/running-a-script-during-booting-startup-init-d-vs-cron-reboot) or [configure the service controller](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/public-cloud-forum/4315/start-service-on-boot-in-ubuntu).

or use `@reboot` in crontab.

you should add what you've written in crontab to make us understand what's wrong, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@reboot` in `crontab` doesn't work, for this specific application.

I created a `/etc/rc.local`, `chmod u+x /etc/rc.local`.

Here we have the contents of the `/etc/rc.local` file

`openvpn ~/file.ovpn`

after rebooting the server, it successfully connected.